# SQL Server Vocabulary table problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a project that I'm working on, it's kind of... say it's a quiz.

Each registered user can sign in to this system (ASP.NET MVC project) and answer easy questions that only requires one word as an answer. Each word starts at level 1, max is level 5, if you fail answering a question, you get -1 and +1 if you give the correct answer, no big deal.

My problem here is that I don't know how to create this SQL model to store the -1 and +1 (range from 1-5) data in the same table for all registered users. Sure I can store everything in one or two cells separated by commas, but that's way to ugly. I want to focus on using foreign keys for this approach (or?). So far I've created the basic structure since I'm not sure how to create the above described approach.

As I've said, each correct answer (one word answer), raises +1 (range 1-5) for that word. Each word/answer should be connected to all users and to which level each user accessed. Please help me connect the dots here, thank you.

This is the basic structure so far.

```
create table Users
(
    Id int primary key not null identity,
    Username nvarchar(256) not null,
    Password nvarchar(256) not null
);
go

create table Words
(
    Id int primary key not null identity,
    Words nvarchar(256) not null,
    Answers nvarchar(256) not null,
    TimeStamp DateTime not null
);
go
```

Comment: I think we'll need quite a bit more information. Can a registered user answer a whole series of questions on different days? How many questions are there?

Comment: The questions are random and there are several questions, at least 10 questions at the moment. There's no limits, days doesn't matter, but when a word reaches level 5 that word wont came back again for the users who reached that level.